# How to make a list that displays the top level subpages, and any subpages or siblings off of the current page

Tags: wordpress

Lets say we are displaying a few family trees. We are currently on the family tree top-page,and we need our list to look like this:

*Family Trees*

- The Smiths
- The Joneses
- The Does

When the user clicks the Smiths, we want the list to look like this:

*The Smiths*

- The Smiths

  - Dave
  - Steve
  - Dolly
- The Joneses
- The Does

And when a user clicks on Steve, we want the list to also look like this:

*Dave Smith*

- The Smiths

  - Dave
  - Steve
  - Dolly
- The Joneses
- The Does

So, we need to display a list of all subpages and siblings of the current page, as well as all siblings of every step in the hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember I read something about this in one of the blogs I follow. Take a look at [**456bereastreet**](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201010/creating_a_hierarchical_submenu_in_wordpress/).

Comment: Also this, which that blog links to: http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/selective-page-hierarchy-for-wp_list_pages/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a lot more information:

- Is this information coming out of a database or are they static pages?
- How is the navigation currently being generated?
- What programming language?
- Is there a content management system involved?
- Do you need this to change without page reloads, or are you OK with page reloads?

Comment: You might notice the wordpress tag.